# Multisized List arrange using CSS - Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently having a problem trying to set to the left every sublist of the navigation bar so that it aligns correctly bellow every sublist if there is more than 6 columns, the problem happens from the 7th list. I'm using bootstrap and every sublist have a size of 2 (so from the 7th as it passes the 12 column size it moves down, as expected)

What I'm getting a result is

[image: Page Before]

And the expected result is

[image]

Piece of code used per list:

```
<div class="sub-navigation-section col-md-2">Ul and li inside</div>
```

The CSS that is attempting to do the expected result is a `Float:left;`

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap uses a 12 column grid system so you won't be able to divide that up equally into 7 columns.  You could do this by creating your own class that has a width of approx 14.285% (100/7) and the same properties as the bootstrap col-* classes (float left etc)... but remember you'll need to cater for different viewports etc

Comment: So, there is no way to fix it with some CSS? Problem is, they are using some Hybris template where they use bootstrap for the responsive, the small window size works well, but on the large window size that happens

Comment: No, you can achieve this purely with css.     You need to create custom classes that won't make your 7 column layout exceed 100% width

Answer (score 0):

If you wont use javascript, you can alternatively use CSS3´s `column-gap` and `column-width` like in this example:

https://www.bootply.com/118335

It floats the boxes like waterfall layout. Hope this helps you.